# How to check google play services version and firebase version in react-native project?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-push-notification, react-notifications

I am trying to install `rn-push-notifications` in react-native project for which I need the google play services version and firebase version. Could you please assist me?

Comment: I think you could use any compatible versions. For example : `googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.1.0"` &
`firebaseVersion = "17.3.4"`

Answer (score 13):

I use this method:

First run `./gradlew app:dependencies`. You could send its output to a file for further searching.

Then search in the output for version of **com.google.android.gms:play-services-base** and **com.google.firebase:firebase-core**.

Answer (score 11):

@Mohsen's answer was helpful to me to implement a react native app which has **push notifications**.

First I installed dependency [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

Then I navigated to the **android** folder and ran this command `gradlew app:dependencies`

Form the output of terminal, I found `googlePlayServicesVersion` and `firebaseMessagingVersion` by searching
**com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement** and
**com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging**

Further, to find `supportLibVersion` [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59795781/10564312) was helped

Comment: command have to be 
 ./gradlew app:dependencies

Answer (score 1):

use command

```
cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies | grep 'dependency_name_here'
```

eg.

```
cd android && ./gradlew app:dependencies | grep 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
```