# Get "supportLibVersion" , "playServicesVersion" and "androidMapsUtilsVersion" Value in configuration react-native-maps

Tags: javascript, google-play-services, react-native, react-native-maps

I am installing `react-native-maps`. In the installation guide, on [Build configuration on Android](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md#build-configuration-on-android) in Section 3.1, it shows:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "xxx"
        minSdkVersion = xxx
        compileSdkVersion = xxx
        targetSdkVersion = xxx
        supportLibVersion = "xxx"
        playServicesVersion = "xxx" // or set latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "xxx"
    }
}
...
```

How can i get  `supportLibVersion` , `playServicesVersion`  and `androidMapsUtilsVersion` values?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In general, all libaries can be found in the maven repository. For some you have to see a concrete library to get the version number (*this number is the number you put in the build.grade file*). Usually, all libraries that are part of a group, should support the same version numbers (otherwise you get a compile error and you need to check the concrete version and make sure that it exists for the libraries that you need).

**googlePlayServicesVersion:**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-maps

**androidMapsUtilsVersion:**
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.maps.android/android-maps-utils

**supportLibVersion:**
https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=com.android.support
See within a library. e.g. https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7

Comment: thank you for all the links! you're a hero !

Answer (score 16):

try this:

```sh
ext {
    compileSdkVersion           = 28
    targetSdkVersion            = 28
    buildToolsVersion           = "28.0.3"
    googlePlayServicesVersion   = "17.0.0"
    supportLibVersion           = "27.1.0"
    androidMapsUtilsVersion     = "0.5+"
    minSdkVersion               = 16
}
```

Comment: As someone stumbling on this... Where are you supposed to find out the versions of these things? I searched everywhere and couldn't find them.

Comment: @SaltedBlowfish I added an answer, that should clarify your question.

Comment: supportLibVersion = "29"
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.0"

Comment: Hi, is it supposed to be playServicesVersion or googlePlayServicesVersion ??